# Understanding a C program

Tags: c

Hi I have the following program, I understand how pipes work and fork() etc.. but I have a question. why this program doesn't print "baz\n" 
the result is : 
bar
foo

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(){
    int fd[2];
    char buf[32];

    pipe(fd);
    if(fork()==0){
        dup2(fd[1],1);
        printf("foo");
    }
    else{
        read(fd[0],buf,31);
        execl("/bin/echo","/bin/echo","bar",buf,0);
        printf("baz\n");

    }

}
```

Comment: `man execl` will help you understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your program doesn't write "baz" because it runs at first your **execl** function, which close the created process of your fork. In other words, you have to put your printf **before** the exec function :

```
else{
    read(fd[0],buf,31);
    printf("baz\n");
    execl("/bin/echo","/bin/echo","bar",buf,0);
}
```

Good luck ! :)

Comment: thank you Actually i don't want to write baz i just want to understand why, now i Do. Thank you for your answers

Comment: @spleeftroner If Gangai Johann's answer solved your question, you should mark it as correct.

Comment: I did it's just because i's been less than 9 minutes so I couldn't choose it as a correct answer ;)

Answer (score 1):

Execl doesn't return back to the original program. It replaces the current process with a new process (the old one wouldn't keep running). It will execute `execl("/bin/echo","/bin/echo","bar",buf,0);` and never come back to execute the `printf`. This is why you only get `"bar foo"` as a result.

If you look at the man pages:

http://linux.die.net/man/3/execl

Look at the first paragraph under description.

Comment: Like @Gangai said you can just swap the two around.